# How to run one jQuery animation function on multiple elements simultaneously?

Tags: jquery, animation

The idea is to make a certain number of elements sway, and to use only one function to do it (I assume that's the best option). I made a function that would make a single element sway, ***which worked really well***, but then I tried to make this apply to multiple elements and I ran into real problems.

What's complicating this is that the sway function is designed to generate a slightly different diameter and speed each time its called, so the swaying looks natural. It's also made to loop the motion indefinitely.

Thus the function is broken into three parts, **the first** setting up the array of elements it will apply to, **the second** (called main) generating the variables necessary for that elements swaying, and **the third** (called act) to run and loop the sway animation.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Balloon Proof of Concept Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var now;
            var balloons = new Array();
            balloons[0] = "#box1"
            balloons[1] = "#box2"
            balloons[2] = "#box3"

            var main = function(hello) {

                var speed = Math.random() * (2500 - 2000 + 1) + 2000;
                var change = Math.random() * (35 - 10 + 1) + 10;

                var act = function() {
                    $(hello).animate({
                        left : change
                    }, speed);
                    $(hello).animate({
                        left : -change
                    }, speed);
                    act();
                }
                act();
            }

        for( now = 0; now < balloons.length; now++) {
                main(balloons[now]);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="box" id="box1" style="margin-left:300px; margin-top:60px">
        Proj 1
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box2" style="margin-left:500px; margin-top:20px">
        Proj 2
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box3" style="margin-left:700px; margin-top:50px">
        Proj 3
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I **expected** the function might get stuck on the first array element at the loop, and now that the basic code has been fixed I'm in exactly that situation. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this, or alternative methods.

The CSS is very simple, just some basic styling

```
.box {
width:100px;
height:100px;
position: absolute;
background-color:red;}

.html .body {position: absolute;}
```

Comment: `$(hello)` is actually calling `$(0)` `$(1)` `$(2)` which obviously does nothing. Logic error or typo. Should be `main(balloons[now])` instead of `main(now)`

Comment: Thank you for that, updating immediately

Comment: @KevinB good spot, but it's the least of his problems ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak That's why it is a comment and not an answer, ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you call `.animate()` it *queues* the animation, and then returns immediately.

Since you're then calling `act` again recursively the code just goes into an infinite loop.

Try this, instead:

```
function act() {
    $(hello)
       .animate({ left :  change }, speed)
       .animate({ left : -change }, speed, act);
}
```

i.e. register `act` as the *completion callback* of the second phase of the animation.

Comment: That's amazing, I have no idea why that works though. Why isn't this generating a queue of 'act's like before?

Comment: @OlivierButler because callbacks are ultimately triggered by the JS event loop - this might _look_ recursive, but it actually isn't, since the new version always terminates immediately and then _some time later_ it's called again.

Comment: So the function is adding the first two to the queue, moving on to the other array elements before coming back and acting again? This is really helpful thank you very much.

Comment: @OlivierButler yes, except that it doesn't come back to each element until each has finished a whole left to right (and back again) swing.

Comment: Oh I see, so by putting act at the end of the animate effect is that using the 'complete' function of the jQuery API or is it a general rule of javascript that such syntax waits for the function to complete before coming round?

P.S. If you get bored of my pestering I can understand, I could ask questions like these for a while I'm sure

Comment: @OlivierButler that's a jQuery `.animate` feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer, this will repeat the movement after a period of time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        $(document).ready(function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            var now;                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            var balloons = new Array();                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            balloons[0] = "#box1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            balloons[1] = "#box2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            balloons[2] = "#box3"                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

            var main = function(hello) {                                                                                                                                                                                                           

                var speed = Math.random() * (2500 - 2000 + 1) + 2000;                                                                                                                                                                              
                var change = Math.random() * (35 - 10 + 1) + 10;                                                                                                                                                                                   

                var act = function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                    $(hello).animate({                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                        left : change                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                    }, speed);                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                    $(hello).animate({                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                        left : -change                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                    }, speed);                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                act();                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                setInterval( act, 1000);                                                                                                                                                                                                           

            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
var now = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
for( now = 0; now < balloons.length; now++) {                                                                                                                                                                                              
     main(balloons[now]);                                                                                                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

});
```

Comment: umm, no, that'll cause some nasty effects depending on whether the timeout completes within 1000ms or not.  At best it'll pause, at worst (after a long time) the animation queue will fill up and the browser will run out of memory.

Comment: Of course you shouldn't use direct recursion as in your example function act() { act()} this will break the processing in the browser.

Comment: that's not my point - in your version you're adding entries to the animation queue 4x - 5x faster than they're removed.

Comment: I thought that was an acceptable way to create a loop, (irrespective of the delay method), when you say break the processing do you mean fill up all the memory, or just prevent the function from moving on any further?

Comment: The way you did it there were no delay. The animate method works asynchronous. Which means the delay is processed "in the background" and the app continues instantly executing act() again.

Comment: It's strange then because the browser seemed quite happy with that set up before I added array elements, I mean I stared at it for quite a while and the computer gave no sign of becoming overloaded.

Comment: Use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) to see this errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe easier to follow if rearranged as follows:

```
$(function(){
    function act(jqObj, speed, change) {
        jqObj.animate({
            'left': change // stage 1
        }, speed).animate({
            'left': -change // stage 2
        }, speed, function(){
            act(jqObj, speed, change); // repeat stages 1 and 2 (indefinitely)
        });
    };
    var balloons = [ // array of jQuery objects.
        $("#box1"),
        $("#box2"),
        $("#box3")
    ];
    for (i = 0; i < balloons.length; i++) {
        var speed = 2000 + Math.random() * 501;
        var change = 10 + Math.random() * 26;
        act(balloons[i], speed, change);
    }
});
```

See working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BWbJj/1/).

Comment: And more concisely, try [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/BWbJj/5/). The code is more advanced, exploiting jQuery's `.each()` method. If you can follow it, then you are doing well.

Comment: Well I understand the principles, the role of i and el completely perplex me though. My current struggle is to use the animate function to modify the co-ordinates of an svg line using the svg jQuery plugin, so far I've managed to make the line move, but not exactly as intended. Anyway that's some-what tangential, thank you for all your help!

Comment: Actually I've written it up as a question, it went beyond my initial thoughts that I'd miss-typed something, I don't know how wide the knowledge base is on using the SVG jquery plugin though.